# Cannot see authorize dialog when user wants to install my app

Tags: facebook, oauth, installation

i have created an facebook application

when trying to access the application for the first time 
i don't see the dialog asking to authorize the application
i only see a facebook logo , 
only when pressing the link under the logo i can see the auth dialog 
what i am doing is to redirect the client to this URL

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=my client number&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmy-side-domain.com%3A9000%2F&scope=read_stream,user_birthday,user_location

can u tell me what i am missing 
(it redirect ok under chrome , but not on firefox)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a canvas app on facebook.com?  What you are describing sound like what happens when you do a redirect to the oauth dialog in a canvas app within the canvas iframe.  You need to bust out of the iframe during the redirect:

> Because of the way that we currently load iframes for Apps on
>   Facebook.com, it is important that you navigate the top window of the
>   user's browser to the OAuth Dialog. Many apps do this by sending a
>   script fragment to the user's browser setting the top.location.href
>   property to the dialog URL.

source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth

Comment: ok i add my link inside a script tag with the top.location ,now i get the dialog with a "An error occurred. Please try again later."

Comment: this is the url he tryis to get to "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CODE&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FMY_DOMAINcom%3A9000%2F&amp;scope=read_stream,user_birthday,user_location"